# Does iOS deallocate data loaded in UITabBar tabs when it needs some extra memory?

Tags: ios, memory, uitabbar

I'm just curious if it will automatically deallocate data in UITabBar tabs that aren't currently open, whenever it is running out of memory and extra memory is needed.

Also, sorry if this question is completely wrong and sounds like I am just making something up. I'm just asking this because I swear I heard somewhere that when iOS is low on memory it starts looking for things to deallocate, and deallocates them.

Correct me if I am wrong. Thank you!

Comment: By "tabs", do you specifically mean a [UITabBar](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/UIElementGuidelines/UIElementGuidelines.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH13-SW52)?

Comment: @esker Yes, sorry for not clairifying. I am referring to tabs in the UITabBar.

Comment: You should edit the question title

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the data will not be automatically deallocated.

The view controllers contained in them will receive a call to -(void)didReceiveMemoryWarning; It's up to you to decide what can be deallocated to free up memory.

There's more details here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ViewLoadingandUnloading/ViewLoadingandUnloading.html